# detect how long has user played video JW player 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I'm using JW Player 7 javsacript version. It is really nice. But my videos are hosted on Amazon S3. Now I'd like to know is there any way to detect how long has user played video or how many seconds the video was played?

Comment: in on pause event you can call `getPosition()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [JWPlayer's documentation](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference):

Look at the API call, `getPosition()`.

```
var currentPlayTime = jwplayer().getPosition();
```

Comment: With this code I could track that: jwplayer("mySingleVideoWrapper").onTime(function (event){ jQuery("#getCurrentPositionOfVideo").val(event.position);}). One question - how can I check if user played at least 30% of each video, how can I check this ? if(event.position = "what can I write here to check that" ) {} ? @PaparazzoKid

Comment: @aidaghazaryan: there is another API call: `getDuration()`. With some basic math, you can get the percentage.